# Вырезать последний тег и его содержимое

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Есть текст, в котором следующие содержание:

```
<div class="my_text">
   <p>первый абзац</p>
   <p>Второй</p>
   Текст без тегов
   <p>Последний абзац</p>
</div>
```

Вопрос: Каким образом вырезать самый последний абзац

и его содержимое? 
Учитывая то что абзацов может быть неопределенное количество, но вырезать всегда нужно только последний.

Буду благодарен за регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 3):

Если на php, то SimpleHtmlDom библиотека вам в помощь.
Там есть что-то типа (синтаксис лучше проверить, там есть доки)

```
$ret = $html->find(".div1", 0)->last_child();
```

Ну и собственно ремув его, а потом из класса SimpleHtmlDom получить модифицированный HTML

Answer (score 0):

а абзацы всегда в тегах `<p>`? теги `<p>` должны быть включены в вырезанную строку? переводы строк есть?

```
$needle = substr($string, strrpos($string, "<p>"), -6);
```

Comment: абзац всегда находиться в теге `<p></p>`

Comment: ок. должно сработать. если известно количество символов от конца текста до закрывающего тега `</p>` можно не вычислять разницу между позициями тегов, а задать отрицательно значение в третьем параметре mb_substr, например -5 отрежет до 5го символа с конца.

Comment: как то не правильно работает. в одном вырезало просто весь текст

Comment: поправил код. теперь правильно работает?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с регуляркой. Но могут возникунить проблемы, если есть вложенные div.

```
preg_match('#<div\s+class="my_text">.*<p>(.*)<\/p>\s?<\/div>#is', $data, $result);
echo($result[1]);
```

Простой вариант с применением SimpleHTMLDom. Ищется последний элемент div'а:

```
$dom = str_get_html($data);
$p = $dom->find('div[@class="my_text"]', 0)->last_child();
echo $p->innertext;
```

Более надежный вариант с применением SimpleHTMLDom. Ищется последний 'p' элемент:

```
$dom = str_get_html($data);
$lst = $dom->find('div[@class="my_text"]/p');
$p = $lst[count($lst)-1];
echo $p->innertext;
```

P.S. $data содержит ваш текст